# Build fails due to architecture deprecation error

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I am building a Unity project to my device on Xcode. I started using cocapods to fix another issue.

Now I am getting this error:

> The armv7 architecture is deprecated. You should update your ARCHS build setting to remove the armv7 architecture.

What does this error mean and how to get rid of it?

Comment: You must be using xCode 14 : iOS 10 and below are no more supported which correspond to 32 bits processor armv7. If you need to build for older iPhone you need to download xCode 13.4.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason the default iOS target was set to be really old.

Comment: Any Fix for this @PeetuNuottajärvi

Comment: I would love to know if anyone has a work around for the deprecated 32 bit architecture.  Using XCode 13.x isn't an option as 13.x doesn't include critical iOS 16.x support.  I understand Apple wanting to no longer support these devices.

Comment: I updated my xCode to 14.

Answer (score 0):

This archietecture was depricated in the latest XCode. You can change the archietecture under build setting to the default one.

**Open Project> Build Settings> Archietectures > Select the default one.**

This resolves my issue